# About passing variable between multiple pages using URL

Tags: php, variables

I tried to pass a variable from a radio type form using an url to another page, however it not working and it show nothing on the next page. Here is my code:

Page 1 :

```
<form>
Question 1: 1+1= <br> <input type = "radio" name="q11" value="a1"> 1<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q11" value ="a2"> 2<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q11" value ="a3"> 3<br>

</form>

<a href="page2.php?q11=<?php echo $q11;?>">Next page</a>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
    if(isset($q11)){
    $q11 = $_GET['q11'];
    echo $q11;
    }
?>
```

My guess is the 'q11' in the form is not a variable, however i don't know how to fix it.
(note that i musn not use the submit button, it must be a link)

Also, I have to pass this q11, along with q2 in page 2 to submit them to another page, but I have no idea how to implement it. I tried this code but it also not work.

Page 2:

```
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<?php
        if(isset($q11)){
        $q11 = $_GET['q11'];
        echo $q11;
        }
?>//or assume that i can pass the variable
Question 3: Your age ?<br> <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="a"> 15-<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="b"> 15-25<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="c"> 25-35<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Page 3:

```
<?php
    $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
    $q11 = $_POST['q11'];
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try sessions?

Comment: If you're doing a form submission, then you can't have a clickable link. links don't submit forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(isset($q11)){
    $q11 = $_GET['q11'];
```

must be :

```
  if(isset($_GET['q11']){
    $q11 = $_GET['q11'];
```

if you want to pass q11 from p1 to p2 then to p3 so put hidden field or put it in session/cookies

+

```
<a href="page2.php?q11=<?php echo $q11;?>">Next page</a>
```

that will never work the php is execut on server, you choose q11 in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your form tag is not valid HTML because it has no valid action attribute. More importantly, you are not handling the form properly. You are assuming that when the user clicks the radio button she is causing a variable to be set but your code does not do this.

There are a couple of different ways you could do this. I will focus on the way that will enhance your knowledge of handling forms with PHP

1. Add the following attributes to your form HTML tag: method="post" action="page2.php"
2. On page2.php:

   if (isset($_POST['q11'])) { 
     $q11 = $_POST['q11'];
   }

I'm not sure why you want to use a link instead of a submit. If you are going to use a link you will have to write some JavaScript to handle the form submit